# Access CaseHistory field "Action" in Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, case

On a Case there is a related object called CaseHistory ([docs here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casehistory.htm#topic-title)) which shows the changes to the Case. There is a related list on Case which looks like this:

[image: Case History Related List]

I would like to be able to access the "Action" for each CaseHistory record. However, this is not actually shown in the [list of fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casehistory.htm#topic-title) available on CaseHistory. Is there any way to get this value so I can put it in my own table on a Visualforce page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are building your own table/list based on the case history collection, then you can try something like

```
<apex:outputText value="Changed {!ch.Field} From {!ch.OldValue} to {!ch.NewValue}" />
```

where ch is an element of the collection (mostly the iteration variable of `apex:repeat`)

Comment: I think as @Vamsi has pointed out, the Action field does not exists, it is just a string the the new and old values and some text inserted to say Changed X from A to B.

Comment: What about when the record is created? With your solution we'd have "Changed created From to"

Comment: i just shared the approach.. you can add in the required conditions / filters and display the text you need.